# a question about the parameter in this function

Tags: c++, pointers, constants

I have two question about the following code, in particular the `int sum(const int *begin, const int *end)` function. The thing that I don't understand is, what is the `*p` and the `p` in the that function?

Is `*p` a pointer in that function and how about the `p`? Is `p` a variable?  I was reading that: "*In `const int *p`, `*p` (content pointed-to) is constant, but `p` is not constant.*"

I don't quite understand the difference between `*p` and `p` in this function.

My second question is: What is the reason of declaring `const` in:  `const int *p = begin` in the for loop of `int sum(...)`?  Is it because in the signature of `int sum(...)`, there is this `const` being declared for: `const int *p = begin`  ?  I.e. is it because `begin` is being declared as something that is immutable - so that's why in the for loop, we have to declare `begin` is an immutable constant pointed to by the pointer `*p`?

```
/* Function to compute the sum of a range of an array (SumArrayRange.cpp) */
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// Function prototype
int sum(const int *begin, const int *end);

// Test Driver
   int main() {
   int a[] = {8, 4, 5, 3, 2, 1, 4, 8};
   cout << sum(a, a+8) << endl;        // a[0] to a[7]
   cout << sum(a+2, a+5) << endl;      // a[2] to a[4]
   cout << sum(&a[2], &a[5]) << endl;  // a[2] to a[4]
}

// Function definition
// Return the sum of the given array of the range from
// begin to end, exclude end.
int sum(const int *begin, const int *end) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (const int *p = begin; p != end; ++p) {
        sum += *p;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`p` is a pointer variable. `*` has two meaning:

1. It's pointer declaration
2. It's operator applied to `p` variable to take its value

```cpp
const int* p; // (1) p is pointer on immutable int
int x = *p; // (2) let's take value where p points and put it in x
*p = 1; // (2) set value where p points
```

And yes, you are right with `const` for p. It's because `begin` is `const`

Comment: I would mention as well: A pointer means to store the address of something. In declaration, the type before `*` denotes what type "something" has.

Comment: As the pointer is only an address, it's not clear nor relevant what the address actually represent. This might be a global variable, a local variable, or memory which was allocated by `new` or `new[]`. Actually, the pointer allows to access memory regardless how the storage at address was provided.

Comment: Hello thanks for your answer. But I guess my question is why is it that we assign p as a pointer to an immutable constant i.e. begin. But then we also have ++p in the for loop inside int sum()?  Why is it that it is ++p but not ++p*? And why is it that is is p!=end but not *p!= end?

Comment: Does ++p affect where p points at? i.e. does ++p increase begin by one as well? I guess it doesn't because p is declared as a pointer to an immutable "begin". But I don't understand the second entry and third entry inside the condition of the for loop. I don't understand the ++p and the p!= 0.

Comment: `p` is a pointer on int in memory. `p + 1` it's a pointer on the next int in the memory. Try to read some article about pointers and its arithmetic in C/C++. For example [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/pointers-in-c-and-c-set-1-introduction-arithmetic-and-array/)